# MySQL Simple pivot table with MAX(), GROUP BY and only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm having trouble using `GROUP BY` with `only_full_group_by`.

Here is my `employee_job` table:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+
| id | employee_id | job_id | created_at |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+
|  1 |           2 |     10 | 2019-01-01 |
|  2 |           3 |     20 | 2019-01-01 |
|  3 |           3 |     21 | 2019-02-01 |
|  4 |           3 |     22 | 2019-03-01 |
|  5 |           4 |     30 | 2019-01-01 |
|  6 |           4 |     35 | 2019-02-01 |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+
```

I would like to select only the latest lines per `employee_id`, which I think gives me:

```
SELECT *, MAX(created_at)
FROM `employee_job`
GROUP BY employee_id;
```

The thing is, with `only_full_group_by`, which I can't disable, I get an error:

```
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'XXX.employee_job.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Well... I tried to read about that, and it seems I don't get the error. Of course, if I add other fields to the `GROUP BY`, the result still contains multiple times the same id.

Can someone explain to me how to group my results, maybe if `GROUP BY` isn't the best way to do it, what is, please?

Comment: Well, which `job_id` will you want for employee 3?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @RickJames I want rows 1, 4 and 6, because these are the latest `job_id` for each individual `employee_id`

Comment: @stickybit MySQL 5.7

Comment: Then you need a "groupwise-max" solution.  See the added tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ties, i.e. when an employee has two jobs on the same day, that happen to be the latest one display both, you can join a derived table with query doing the aggregation.

```
SELECT ej1.*
       FROM employee_job ej1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT ej2.employee_id,
                               max(ej2.created_at) created_at
                               FROM employee_job ej2
                               GROUP BY ej2.employee_id) ej2
                       ON ej2.employee_id = ej1.employee_id
                          AND ej2.created_at = ej1.created_at;
```

If you want to eliminate ties and say you want the one with the largest ID in such a case, add another level.

```
SELECT ej1.*
       FROM employee_job ej1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT max(ej2.id) id
                               FROM employee_job ej2
                                    INNER JOIN (SELECT ej3.employee_id,
                                                       max(ej3.created_at) created_at
                                                       FROM employee_job ej3
                                                       GROUP BY ej3.employee_id) ej3
                                               ON ej3.employee_id = ej2.employee_id
                                                  AND ej3.created_at = ej2.created_at
                               GROUP BY ej2.employee_id,
                                        ej2.created_at) ej2
                       ON ej2.id = ej1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's insane how long the query is with `only_full_group_by` for a "simple" need as that. How would you write it if, instead of selecting the largest `id` when ties are found, the line with the latest `created_at` was selected?

Comment: BTW, could you please explain me why my request (in my first post) isn't valid with `only_full_group_by`? I've read the error, and read the explanation online, I don't understand why a nested query is needed to achieve that

Comment: @Max13: I think you may not have fully understood my answer. If the `created_at` is unique per employee both queries will get the row with the latest `created_at` per employee. But if the `created_at` isn't unique per employee you need a second criteria if you don't want to have the ties in the result. Say Bob  had a job A on 2019-07-21 with ID 1 and also a job B with ID 2 on the same day, 2019-07-21. If you want both jobs A and B go with the first query, otherwise with the second to only get job B.

Comment: @Max13: You just can't have a column that isn't in the `GROUP BY` or an argument to an aggregation function in the list of `SELECT`ed columns, because it leave undefined which value should be take from that column in the group. Without `only_full_group_by` you my just get a random value each time you execute the query.

Comment: @Max13: BTW, the task could be achieved with a little simpler query (in terms of writing it, not in terms of the engine executing it) with window functions which are available since MySQL version 8. Also needs at least one subquery but without a join.

Comment: Ok for your query, thanks. I won't have 2 lines with the same date (and `employee_id`) as in my case, it's not possible to change job 2 times the same day (the first just doesn't apply: will be removed).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification about GROUP BY. Without `only_full_group_by`, if I `SELECT *, MAX(created_at) as created_at`, wouldn't the engine show the exact same set, replacing `created_by` by the largest date of all rows? If it does, isn't `GROUP BY` intended to tell the engine to select the largest date of all rows, BY `employee_id` ? (At least, that's how I understood `GROUP BY`)

Comment: @Max13: The `max(created_at)` would be the maximum in the group. But the values of the other columns (the `*`) could be from any row in the group not necessarily from a row with a maximum `created_at`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96462/discussion-between-max13-and-sticky-bit).